# Handdrawn circle simulation in HTML 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

The **[following code](http://jsfiddle.net/LKRWq/)** creates a circle in HTML 5 Canvas using jQuery:

**Code:**

```
//get a reference to the canvas
var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

DrawCircle(75, 75, 20);

//draw a circle
function DrawCircle(x, y, radius)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
    ctx.fillStyle = 'transparent';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

I am trying to simulate any of the following types of circles:

[image: examples]

I have researched and found this **[article](http://29a.ch/2010/2/10/hand-drawn-lines-algorithm-javascript-canvas-html5)** but was unable to apply it.

I would like for the circle to be drawn rather than just appear.

Is there a better way to do this?  I'm sensing there's going to be a lot of math involved :)

P.S. I like the simplicity of [PaperJs](http://paperjs.org/), maybe this would be the easiest approach using it's simplified paths?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are already good solutions presented here. I wanted to add a variations of what is already presented - there are not many options beyond some trigonometry if one want to simulate hand drawn circles.

I would first recommend to actually record a real hand drawn circle. You can record the points as well as the `timeStamp` and reproduce the exact drawing at any time later. You could combine this with a line smoothing algorithm.

This here solution produces circles such as these:

[image: Snapshot]

You can change color, thickness etc. by setting the `strokeStyle`, `lineWidth` etc. as usual.

To draw a circle just call:

```
handDrawCircle(context, x, y, radius [, rounds] [, callback]);
```

(`callback` is provided as the animation makes the function asynchronous).

The code is separated into two segments:

1. Generate the points
2. Animate the points

**Initialization**:

```
function handDrawCircle(ctx, cx, cy, r, rounds, callback) {

    /// rounds is optional, defaults to 3 rounds    
    rounds = rounds ? rounds : 3;

    var x, y,                                      /// the calced point
        tol = Math.random() * (r * 0.03) + (r * 0.025), ///tolerance / fluctation
        dx = Math.random() * tol * 0.75,           /// "bouncer" values
        dy = Math.random() * tol * 0.75,
        ix = (Math.random() - 1) * (r * 0.0044),   /// speed /incremental
        iy = (Math.random() - 1) * (r * 0.0033),
        rx = r + Math.random() * tol,              /// radius X 
        ry = (r + Math.random() * tol) * 0.8,      /// radius Y
        a = 0,                                     /// angle
        ad = 3,                                    /// angle delta (resolution)
        i = 0,                                     /// counter
        start = Math.random() + 50,                /// random delta start
        tot = 360 * rounds + Math.random() * 50 - 100,  /// end angle
        points = [],                               /// the points array
        deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;                   /// degrees to radians
```

In the main loop we don't bounce around randomly but increment with a random value and then increment linearly with that value, reverse it if we are at bounds (tolerance).

```
for (; i < tot; i += ad) {
    dx += ix;
    dy += iy;

    if (dx < -tol || dx > tol) ix = -ix;
    if (dy < -tol || dy > tol) iy = -iy;

    x = cx + (rx + dx * 2) * Math.cos(i * deg2rad + start);
    y = cy + (ry + dy * 2) * Math.sin(i * deg2rad + start);

    points.push(x, y);
}
```

And in the last segment we just render what we have of points.

The speed is determined by `da` (delta angle) in the previous step:

```
    i = 2;

    /// start line    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0], points[1]);

    /// call loop
    draw();

    function draw() {

        ctx.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);

        i += 2;

        if (i < points.length) {
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        } else {
            if (typeof callback === 'function')
                callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Tip: To get a more realistic stroke you can reduce `globalAlpha` to for example `0.7`.

However, for this to work properly you need to draw solid to an off-screen canvas first and then blit that off-screen canvas to main canvas (which has the `globalAlpha` set) for each frame or else the strokes will overlap between each point (which does not look good).

For squares you can use the same approach as with the circle but instead of using radius and angle you apply the variations to a line. Offset the deltas to make the line non-straight.

I tweaked the values a little but feel free to tweak them more to get a better result.

To make the circle "tilt" a little you can first rotate the canvas a little:

```
rotate = Math.random() * 0.5;

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(cx, cy);
ctx.rotate(-rotate);
ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
```

and when the loop finishes:

```
if (i < points.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
} else {
   ctx.restore();
}
```

(included in the demo linked above).

The circle will look more like this:

[image: Snapshot tilted]

**Update**

To deal with the issues mentioned (comment fields too small :-) ): it's actually a bit more complicated to do animated lines, especially in a case like this where you a circular movement as well as a random boundary.

Ref. comments point 1: the tolerance is closely related to radius as it defined max fluctuation. We can modify the code to adopt a tolerance (and `ix/iy` as they defines how "fast" it will variate) based on radius. This is what I mean by tweaking, to find that value/sweet-spot that works well with all sizes. The smaller the circle the smaller the variations. Optionally specify these values as arguments to the function.

Point 2: since we're animating the circle the function becomes asynchronous. If we draw two circles right after each other they will mess up the canvas as seen as new points are added to the path from both circles which then gets stroked criss-crossed.

We can get around this by providing a callback mechanism:

```
handDrawCircle(context, x, y, radius [, rounds] [, callback]);
```

and then when the animation has finished:

```
if (i < points.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

} else {
    ctx.restore();
    if (typeof callback === 'function')
        callback();  /// call next function
}
```

Another issues one will run into with the code as-is (remember that the code is meant as an example not a full solution :-) ) is with thick lines:

When we draw segment by segment separately canvas does not know how to calculate the butt angle of the line in relation to previous segment. This is part of the path-concept. When you stroke a path with several segments canvas know at what angle the butt (end of the line) will be at. So here we to either draw the line from start to current point and do a clear in between or only small `lineWidth` values.

When we use `clearRect` (which will make the line smooth and not "jaggy" as when we don't use a clear in between but just draw on top) we would need to consider implementing a top canvas to do the animation with and when animation finishes we draw the result to main canvas.

Now we start to see part of the "complexity" involved. This is of course because canvas is "low-level" in the sense that we need to provide all logic for everything. We are basically building systems each time we do something more with canvas than just draw simple shapes and images (but this also gives the great flexibility).

Comment: Wow!  Fantastic answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Two issues perhaps you could shed light on:  1) I notice when I draw a smaller circle, it is more erroneous.  2) When I try to call the function twice (to draw 2 or more circles) the script goes crazy.  http://jsfiddle.net/8w2GZ/4/

Comment: @user1477388 hi and thanks! I updated my answer with possible solutions (the comment field got too tiny :-) ).

Comment: Thanks for the update.  This is more mathematical than most of the applications I build (I build business systems which tend to be more logical than mathematical).  I would like to be good at both, so are there any references you would suggest?  For instance, something that would shed light on the purpose of `ix,iy,rx,ry`, etc. and how you came to craft this solution?

Comment: @user1477388 I use them in relation dx/dy (ix/iy increments them respectively). So when dx/dy reaches tolerance they get negated to move the other way. As to crafting it: I knew it at least had to simulate the variations in "centrifugal" force (strong word here :-) ) but it needed to be smooth hence the small increment values. Originally I wanted to use physics to simulate a drag around the circle's path but I found it a bit overkill so a simple compromise was used instead. I am mostly used to business apps too but I did lot of fun math and low-level stuff in the 80/90s on the CBM Amiga.

Comment: @user1477388 rx and ry are radius for x and y axis respectively as we draw an ellipse instead of an circle those has to be separated.

Comment: Outstanding work! I took the liberty of adding some variation in the width of the line (http://jsfiddle.net/0397mkf4/). This can be tuned with the parameters to lineWidth(). I didnt bubble these up through the function calls since its getting rather voluminous. A library solution would probably use an option object.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some basics I created for this answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/TPDmn/

Basically, when you draw a circle, you need to account for hand imperfections. So, in the following code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src="data:image/png;base64,...";

var ctx = $('#sketch')[0].getContext('2d');
function draw(x,y) {
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}

for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
    var radiusError = +10 - i/20;
    var d = 2*Math.PI/360 * i;
    draw(200 + 100*Math.cos(d), 200 + (radiusError+80)*Math.sin(d) );
}
```

Pay attention how vertical radiusError changes when the angle (and the position) grows. You are welcome to play with this fiddle until you get a "feel" what component does what. E.g. it would make sense to introduce another component to radiusError that emulates "unsteady" hand by slowly changing it my random amounts.

There are many different ways to do this. I choose trig functions for the simplicity of the simulation, as speed is not a factor here.

Update:

This, for example, will make it less perfect:

```
var d = 2*Math.PI/360 * i;
var radiusError = +10 - i/20 + 10*Math.sin(d);
```

Obviously, the center of the circle is at (200,200), as the formula for drawing a circle (rather, ellipsis with vertical radius RY and horizontal radius RX) with trigonometric functions is

```
x = centerX + RX * cos ( angle )
y = centerY + RY * sin ( angle )
```

Comment: +1 Inventive use of using radius "errors" to introduce variety to the circle!

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  How does the png part work?  Where can I view it?  I would like to change the size of the stroke (and maybe the color).  Also, I was originally wanting to animate the drawing of the circle (not just have it appear on canvas).  Thanks again for a great answer to this question!

Comment: @user1477388 I've created an animated version (may not be the cleanest though): http://jsfiddle.net/TPDmn/2/

Answer (score 3):

Your task seems to have 3 requirements:

1. A hand-drawn shape.
2. An “organic” rather than “ultra-precise” stroke.
3. Revealing the circle incrementally instead of all-at-once.

To get started, check out this nice on-target demo by Andrew Trice.

This amazing circle is hand drawn by me (you can laugh now...!)

[image: My amazing circle created with Andrew's technique]

Andrew's demo does steps 1 and 2 of your requirements.

It lets you hand draw a circle (or any shape) using an organic looking “brush effect” instead of the usual ultra-precise lines normally used in canvas.

It achieves the “brush effect” by  by repeated drawing a brush image between hand drawn points

Here’s the demo:

http://tricedesigns.com/portfolio/sketch/brush.html#

And the code is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/triceam/HTML5-Canvas-Brush-Sketch

Andrew Trice’s demo draws-and-forgets the lines that make up your circle.

Your task would be to impliment your third requirement (remembering strokes):

- Hand draw a circle of your own,
- Save each line segment that makes up your circle in an array,
- “Play” those segements using Andrew’s stylized brush technique.

Results: A hand-drawn and stylized circle that appears incrementally instead of all at once.

You have an interesting project…If you feel generous, please share your results!

Answer (score 1):

[See live demo here.](http://codepen.io/dcdev/full/upjDy/)  Also available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/d9995b8f12e23063f17c).

```
<div id="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox='-1.5 -1.5 3 3'></svg>
</div>
```

---

```
#container {
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}
path.ln {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: #666;
  fill: none;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s ease-in forwards;
  -moz-animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
  -o-animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
  animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

---

```
function path(δr_min,δr_max, el0_min, el0_max, δel_min,δel_max) {

    var c = 0.551915024494;
    var atan = Math.atan(c)
    var d = Math.sqrt( c * c + 1 * 1 ), r = 1;
    var el = (el0_min + Math.random() * (el0_max - el0_min)) * Math.PI / 180;
    var path = 'M';

    path += [r * Math.sin(el), r * Math.cos(el)];
    path += ' C' + [d * r * Math.sin(el + atan), d * r * Math.cos(el + atan)];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        el += Math.PI / 2 * (1 + δel_min + Math.random() * (δel_max - δel_min));
        r *= (1 + δr_min + Math.random()*(δr_max - δr_min));
        path += ' ' + (i?'S':'') + [d * r * Math.sin(el - atan), d * r * Math.cos(el - atan)];
        path += ' ' + [r * Math.sin(el), r * Math.cos(el)];
    }

    return path;
}

function cX(λ_min, λ_max, el_min, el_max) {
    var el = (el_min + Math.random()*(el_max - el_min));
    return 'rotate(' + el + ') ' + 'scale(1, ' + (λ_min + Math.random()*(λ_max - λ_min)) + ')'+ 'rotate(' + (-el) + ')';
}

function canvasArea() {
    var width = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 450);
  var height = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 250);
    $('#container').width(width).height(height);
}
d3.selectAll( 'svg' ).append( 'path' ).classed( 'ln', true) .attr( 'd', path(-0.1,0, 0,360, 0,0.2 )).attr( 'transform', cX( 0.6, 0.8, 0, 360 ));

setTimeout(function() { location = '' } ,5000)
```

Comment: Nice work!  Thanks for sharing that.  From a programming perspective, I typically don't like to see special characters such as λ and δ in the code though :(

Comment: Thanks.  The majority of the credit goes to [Patrick Surry](https://gist.github.com/patricksurry/11087975) whom I forked.  I just improved upon their code.  You have a point, I will def. make a note to adjust that (may get to it this evening or sometime this week).  Thanks for checking it out.